# How to get the selected value from the list of dropdown using Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

This is the View model

```
 self.choiceSelect = ko.observable();
            self.selectedItems = ko.observableArray([]);
            self.selectedComponent = ko.observable();
            self.componentList = ko.observableArray();

 self.GetData = function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: self.url + "GetComponent",
                type: "GET",
                cache: false
            })
            .fail(function (qxhr, status, errorThrown) {

            })
            .done(function (data) {

                self.componentList(data);

            });

        };
```

This is the code:

```
<select id="report-Components" data-bind="value: selectedComponent, options: componentList, optionsText: 'componentName'"></select><br /><br />
<h4>Component Attributes</h4>
<!-- ko if: selectedComponent  -->
<!-- ko if: selectedComponent().componentField  -->
<div data-bind="foreach: selectedComponent().componentField">
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $parent.selectedItems, value: $data" />
        </div>
        <label class="control-label">
            <strong data-bind="text: fieldText"></strong>
        </label>
    </div>                                    
</div>
<!-- /ko -->                            
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: selectedItems  -->
<div data-bind="foreach: selectedItems">
    <!-- ko if: fieldChoice.length > 0  -->
    <label data-bind="text: fieldText"></label>
    <select data-bind="options: fieldChoice, optionsText: 'choiceName', value: $data.choiceSelect"></select>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: fieldChoice.length == 0  -->
    <label data-bind="text: fieldText"></label>
    <input type="text" value=""/>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>  
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to bind the select value to an observable:

```
<select data-bind="options: fieldChoice, optionsText: 'choiceName', value: $data.nameOfObservable">
```

This should update nameOfObservable when the select is changed.

This observable needs to be on each item in your array that you are looking over. So whatever objects you are storing in selectedItems, they need to have an observable property with the same name.

To make everything in your view model observable, I recommend using the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html):

```
self.componentList = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
```

And do the same for the other properties on your view model.

Comment: But here i created multiple dropdown using foreach and if I bind with observable, it doesn't work

Comment: Well, you would have to bind each select to a different observable, but then why wouldn't you be doing that anyway? Just have a separate observable bound to each select.

Comment: But I dont know how many dropdown should appear on page. It will be based on observableArray.

Comment: Yes, but you've got a foreach loop over selectedItems, so each object in that loop needs to have an observable property that you bind to the dropdown. I've updated the code to make that more explicit.

Comment: and where I need to define this observable

Comment: Updated my answer, does that make sense? Otherwise, post what your view model looks like at the moment.

Comment: i have a array which is populated on runtime. Can you please suggest how to add observable into item array. Thanks

Comment: I have bind select value witj $data.choiceSelect (if choiceSelect is observable) but my concern is how to add choiceSelect observable in each item of fieldChoice as mentioned above

Comment: Right, so you have a list of everything that you want in the dropdown in fieldChoice (which isn't shown in your code), yeah, and the selected ones are in selectedItems?

Comment: So basically I need to add observables in each item of fieldChoice. So my concern is how add them (choiceSelect) because fieldChoice is basically an item of selectedItems and on parent i loop through selectedItems and then foreach selectedItems i bind the dropdown with fieldChoice

Comment: See my latest answer for using the mapping plugin to create your view model for you, with observable properties.

Comment: Now suppose in three dropdown I select options then how I get all the data from observable

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you bind an observable as the value of a select, then if you change the select, the observable value will update to the new value. What are you asking?

Comment: for all the dropdown, my value bind with $data.nameOfObservable (as it generate in foreach). So when get the value of $data.nameOfObservable will it return the array of all the selected values in different dropdowns?

Comment: No. The observable is part of whichever object is $data in your foreach loop. There will be no array of selected values. If you want a single observable that returns the selected items as an array, then you need a computed observable on the parent to all these selected item objects, and get it to go through all the objects and return the selectedItem from each one in an array.

Comment: If you want a better answer, then you really need to update your question with your full view model, as this discussion does not make sense as your view model currently stands.